# How to build a Distributed Network with mutual consensus

Tags: distributed-computing, blockchain

What are the technologies needed to build a system which is distributed and maintains a proof of work between parties and transactions.

I've known about Blockchain and worked with IBM Fabric, but they have their own restrictions.

What are the other possible methods and technologies to build such a strong and robust system?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to stay block chain specific, tendermint stepped around the issues of bft by using gossip, for each round, the thing is expecting proof of work hinders scalability, strong consensus is also not very scalable.

Now if we're talking about concepts that can help you build your own solution, rather than framework x, look at event sourcing for sharable immutable transactions, if you need consistency look into chord, it's the easiest way to implement eventual consistency or gossip + crdts, or hell dynamo and cassandra use all 3.

For maintaining security look into the station to station protocol + mutual tls auth.